# Check child row in datatables API

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have this code in js:

```
 $('#db tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
    var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    window.open(data['Link'], data['Details']);
} );
```

When I'm in the child row:

```
$(this).parents('tr')
```

will resolve to the child row, not the parent row. How can I get the parent row first when in the child row? How can I check the class name of the row and 
then get the parent row so I can open the new tab when the button is pressed?

Full code:

Js code:

```
var table = $('#db').DataTable( {
    responsive: true,
    ajax: 'php/table.db.php',
    columns: [
        {
            "data": "first name"
        },
        {
            "data": "last name"
        },
        {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button>Link</button>"
        }
    ],
    select: true,
    lengthChange: false
} );

$('#db tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
    var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    window.open(data['link'], data['first name']);
} );
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-2.2.4/jszip-3.1.3/pdfmake-0.1.27/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/b-1.3.1/b-colvis-1.3.1/b-flash-1.3.1/b-html5-1.3.1/b-print-1.3.1/cr-1.3.3/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.1/r-2.1.1/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/generator-base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/editor.bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-2.2.4/jszip-3.1.3/pdfmake-0.1.27/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/b-1.3.1/b-colvis-1.3.1/b-flash-1.3.1/b-html5-1.3.1/b-print-1.3.1/cr-1.3.3/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.1/r-2.1.1/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/editor.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/table.db.js">
</script>
    <style>
        thead input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 3px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align : center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="bootstrap">
    <div class="container">

        <table data-page-length='25' cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="db" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Link</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Link</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share your html structure

Comment: @chiragsatapara, Ok, please check the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Try .closest(). 
It goes up in the dom until it hits the first match on the selector. 
eg. $(this).closest("tr") will be relative to $(this), going up in dom tree the first tr.

Like: html>body>table>tr>....{anything except tr>...>td>button
if you click the button (=$(this)) you'll get the tr here: html>body>table>tr with .closest("tr").

Comment: I don't quite understand.